# How to upload files from React-native to S3 and store filename via REST API

Tags: django, react-native, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I have dilemma in how to architect my React-native app in the best way using Amazon AWS S3 as image/file storage and Django backend using REST API.

My react-native app has to be able to collect information from user together with couple of images and signatures. I am saving all information as props in redux and I can successfully transfer that to the database using Rest API in Django that I use as backend system. 
I can also send images to Amazon AWS S3 bucket, but that is a separate operation.

My dilemma is if it is good practice to send images to S3 first and then send filename in the REST API call together with other info that is collected from the user in app?

In this way, I have files in the place on S3 and I can use them in the creation of a PDF file that is going to be done by Django backend system.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using AmazonS3 as the storage backend for Django using `S3Boto3Storage`. That will make it a single operation as well as give django access to S3. 
Other option is also to mount S3 as a file system on the machine running django and make the `MEDIA` path as the mounted location. Though, this would add a step of mounting S3 on startup of the machine every time.

Check out this [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html) for the first option.

Comment: Is it possible to send files via REST API, from React-native to Django, together with nested data that goes to multiple tables in database?

Comment: Yes. Are you using `django-rest-framework`? If yes, then if they are nested because of foreign key kinda way then, it offers out of the box by mentioning the `related_name` in the model followed by defining its serializer in the parents serializer class. 

If not using django-rest, you can always write your own POST handler which parses the request and calls the `model.create()` using the data.

Comment: Yes, I am using django-rest-framework. I am using axios to send data to the REST API but does it work using JSON? Some posts suggest using FormData but then I don't know if nested data is supported

Comment: Yes. It does. I use post/put with nested json objects using axios only.